# How do I get the authorization token in express-JWT?

Tags: angular, jwt, express-jwt

When following a simple tutorial regarding authorization with a JWT I have the following code:

```
app.use(expressJwt({secret: 'mojos', algorithms: ['HS256']}).unless({path: ['/api/auth']}));

app.post('/api/auth', function(req, res) {
    
  const body = req.body;

  const user = USERS.find(user => user.username == body.username);
  if(!user || body.password != 'todo') return res.sendStatus(401);
  
  var token = jwt.sign({userID: user.id}, 'mojos', {expiresIn: '2h'});
  res.send({token});
});
```

However when I try to open a route I get an error:

```
app.get('/api/users', function (req, res) {
    res.type("json");
    res.send(getUsers(1));
});
```

Does anybody see what is wrong? If I comment out the app.use line, everything works, however off-course this will not be the goal of the final application.

Answer (score 0):

you don't have to use :

```
        app.use(expressJwt({secret: 'mojos', algorithms: ['HS256']}).unless({path: ['/api/auth']}));
```

just create a token and save it in a cookie

```
     var token = jwt.sign({userID: user.id}, 'mojos', {expiresIn: '2h'});
     res.cookie('CookieName',token,{ maxAge : 1000*60*60*24 /*in ms*/ , httpOnly : true })
```

to get and verify the token use :

```
     const token = req.cookies.CookieName;
       if(token)
       {
        jwt.verify(token,mojos,(err,decodedToken)=>{
        if(err) trow err 
        console.log(decodedToken.userID); //--> will show your the id
       })
      }
      else
      console.log('invalid token')
```

when ever you go to any root, you can access to the token from the req and verify it

last thing , to use `res.cookies` you should install cookie-parser and use :

```
      const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
      app.use(cookieParser())
```